# Нужны ли запятые

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли отмечать запятыми *ха-ха-ха*?

Comment: @Вьилнера, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, это междометие. Другое дело, если междометие повторяется. Напр.: ха-ха-ха, ха-ха-ха, ха-ха-ха.

Answer (score 0):

> **Нужно ли** отмечать запятыми ха-ха-ха?

Только, наверное, не "отмечать", а "выделять"?

**НУЖНО.** См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=130#pp130 :

> § 107. Междометия выделяются (или
> отделяются) запятыми: 
> *— **Ха-ха-ха,** вам странно!*

Comment: @slava1947,автора скорее всего интересует выделяется ли это междометие внутри,т.е. ха,ха,ха, а не выделять его в предложении.